# unity character not moving while jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

hi every one thank you all for reading my question , i am creating forever runner game using unity 5, i want my character to jump above the obstacle but i want the object move forward during the jump, but the jump that i have take a very small time and the character stay very close to the ground,and not moving forward -while jumping- even i am applying a force to it as in the code, so what can i do ?

```
void Start () 
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    verticalJumpPower = 80f;
    horizantalJumpPower = 1000f;
    playerVelocity = 10f;
    isGrounded = true;
}

***in update function :*** 

if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0,verticalJumpPower,horizantalJumpPower));
    anim.SetBool("jump",true);
    isGrounded = false;


    }
```

Comment: Try changing the `ForceMode` type to `ForceMode.Impulse`. i.e. `rBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, verticalJumpPower, horizontalJumpPower), ForceMode.Impulse);`

Comment: it worked for the force applying but the character still not moving forward in the air

Comment: Is this for a 2D game? Check the axes that you have aligned your game world to. You might need to change the Vector3 constructor to `horizontalJumpPower, verticalJumpPower, 0`.

Comment: i am sure i am running in the z diriction

Comment: i added anim.applyRootMotion = false; and it worked

Comment: if this solved your issue answer your own question and accept the answer to close down this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added `anim.applyRootMotion = false;` and it worked